# game developing on android: rotation of text in a canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, rotation, ondraw

I've a problem with my code. When i try to rotate the text everything works, but i want so restore the canvas so i call `canvas.restore();`

When i do that my app will shut down immediately...

a part of my code:

touch one part of the screen:

```
if (wahrheitswert1  == true) { 
    x = 480;
    y = 100;    

    // draw bounding rect before rotating text
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    canvas.translate(x, y);

    // undo the translate
    canvas.translate(-x, -y);
    // rotate the canvas on center of the text to draw
    canvas.rotate(-180, x + rect.exactCenterX(), y + rect.exactCenterY());
    // draw the rotated text
    canvas.drawText("Spieler1 touch", x, y, paint);
    //undo the rotate
    //canvas.restore();
    wahrheitswert1 = false;
    canvas.restore();
}
```

If i don't restore the bitmap i have the background image will be copied from the other site of the screen. 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not used a lot of canvas, I do not see where you save the context before restoring it. I am pretty sure to do a restore on the context you first have to save the context.

Comment: could you please tell me what have i to do?
i'm new in programming an not a java expert

Comment: take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html
notice the restore method mentions you must have previously had a save(). Basically at the point in time you want to restore to, put canvas.save() so when restore is called it restores to the saved point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
Canvas.save()
```

before rotating the Canvas. You can restore the Canvas anytime by calling the Canvas.save().
I've modified your code below.

```
if (wahrheitswert1  == true) { 
    x = 480;
    y = 100;   

    canvas.save();

    // draw bounding rect before rotating text
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    canvas.translate(x, y);

    // undo the translate
    canvas.translate(-x, -y);
    // rotate the canvas on center of the text to draw
    canvas.rotate(-180, x + rect.exactCenterX(), y + rect.exactCenterY());
    // draw the rotated text
    canvas.drawText("Spieler1 touch", x, y, paint);
    //undo the rotate
    //canvas.restore();
    wahrheitswert1 = false;
    canvas.restore();
}
```

I also had the same problem and it worked for me.